# Zend_Feed "description key is missing"

Tags: zend-framework, zend-feed

```
    //CODE
    $entries = $model->fetchEntries();

    $feedUri = '/rss/';
    //link from which feed is available
    $link = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $feedUri;


    $feedArray = array(
            'title' => 'Student\'s Movie Club - Upcoming Movies',
            'link' => $link,
            'description' => 'Upcoming Movies',
            'language' => 'en-us',
            'charset' => 'utf-8',
            'pubDate' => $entries[0]['created'],
            'generator' => 'Zend Framework Zend_Feed',
            'entries' => array()
        );

    foreach ($entries as $movie) {
        $feedArray['entries'][] = array(
            'title' => $movie['movie_title'],
            'link' => '/movie/view/id/'.$movie['id'],
            'description' => $move['movie_review'],
            'pubDate' => $movie['created'],
            'guid' => 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .'/movie/view/id/'.$movie['id']
             );
        }

    //var_dump($feedArray);
    //die();
    $feed = Zend_Feed::importArray($feedArray, 'rss');
    $feed->send();
    //~CODE
```

There is an exception thrown with this message:

```
An error occurred
Application error
Exception information:

Message: description key is missing

Stack trace:

#0 C:\wwwroot\projects\studyhood\project2\library\Zend\Feed\Builder.php(182): Zend_Feed_Builder->_createEntries(Array)
#1 C:\wwwroot\projects\studyhood\project2\library\Zend\Feed.php(385):
```

Any help appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is your problem:

```
'description' => $move['movie_review'],
```

Look at the speling of $movie :) Change your code to this:

```
foreach ($entries as $movie) {
        $feedArray['entries'][] = array(
            'title' => $movie['movie_title'],
            'link' => '/movie/view/id/'.$movie['id'],
            'description' => $movie['movie_review'],
            'pubDate' => $movie['created'],
            'guid' => 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .'/movie/view/id/'.$movie['id']
             );
}
```

Comment: thanks mate...There is another thing i found out..maybe i am wrong maybe not. IF YOU HAVE NULL VALUES IN THE DATABASE (e.g. the $movie['movie_review'] IS_NULL then you will have the same problem..

Cheers.

Comment: This is because `description` is a required key for a feed entry. You might want to add a check if `$movie['movie_review']` is empty and using an arbitrary string if it is. Also, design-wise, I'm not sure if it is intuitive enough to map the movie review with its description since description should actually be required in the database while the movie review should be optional.